# CMake функция find_package() не находит файлы конфигурации config.cmake

Tags: c++, qtcreator, cmake, sdk, cmakelists

Я установил внешнюю библиотеку fCWT по инструкции из оффициального репозитория: https://github.com/fastlib/fCWT

И в стандартном для Ubuntu пути /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake файлы конфигурации **fCWT-config.cmake** и **fCWT-config-release.cmake** присутствуют.

Однако при использовании функции `find_package(fCWT REQUIRED)` в сборке через QT Creator совместно с CMakeLists.txt, CMake выдает ошибку:

> CMakeLists.txt:14: ошибка: By not providing "FindfCWT.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "fCWT", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fCWT" with any of the following names:

> fCWTConfig.cmake

> fcwt-config.cmake

> Add the installation prefix of "fCWT" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "fCWT_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "fCWT" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Это кажется мне странным ведь другую библиотеку, которую я использую в своем небольшом проекте он находит. Мой CMakeLists.txt выглядит следующим образом:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(fft LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH fCWT-config.cmake REQUIRED)
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake/fCWT-config.cmake REQUIRED)
set (fCWT-config.cmake_DIR = /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake/ REQUIRED)
list(APPEND CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake)

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
find_package(fCWT REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${fCWT_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(/lib/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

add_executable(fft main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(fft PRIVATE ${GSL_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(fft PRIVATE ${fCWT_LIBRARY})
```

Как можно видеть, я уже пробовал указать путь до файлов конфигурации в CMAKE_MODULE_PATH и CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Буду рад любым советам по исправлению данной ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Как можно видеть из [документации](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html) *CMake*, переменная `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` предназначена для хранения директорий, где хранятся файлы `<PackageName>-config.cmake` для корректной работы `find_package()`

Вы же в своем коде, мало того, что указываете непосредственно название конфиг файла вместо директории, так еще и дописываете ненужное `REQUIRED` при выставлении переменной `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Еще Вы перезаписываете значение этой переменной, что может привести к проблемам с поиском других пакетов при помощи `find_package()`

Правильным решением будет написать так:

```
# Теперь find_package сможет найти конфиг файл в этой директории
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake/)
find_package(fCWT REQUIRED)

add_executable(fft main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(fft PRIVATE ${fCWT_LIBRARY})
```

и
И если `fCWT-config.cmake` написан правильно, то необходимый `include_directories` уже прописан в нем, а значит в вашем коде он излишен.